# How call findAllById defined on Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I want to use the method findAllById that comes with spring-data, and its supose to be public by spring-data-rest. However i'm not able to make the correct request to call this method, there is no sample on documentation.

i trying something like this:

http://{{host}}:{{port}}/data/?id=1,2,3

but it's not working, any ideas?

Source: https://github.com/nekperu15739/dataSource-WS-REST

Comment: "Not working" in what way? Do you get error messages? Wrong results? Something else? You'll also have to show the actual code you're using (a [mcve].)

Comment: i'm not saying that its not working, i'm saying that i'm trying to use this method but not know how its the request to used, if is possible, because documentation don't mention

Comment: So when you wrote in the question "but it's not working" you were not saying that it's not working?

Comment: in that case its not working as i expect because it give a findAll, instead of findAllById

Answer (score 0):

That method comes with Spring Data but I am not sure if it is, by default, exported as a Rest endpoint.

If it is then it would be under the search path:

e.g. `http://{{host}}:{{port}}/customers/search/findAllById?id=1,2,3`

If it isn't then consider overriding and explicitly exporting.

```
@RestResource(exported = true)
Iterable<Customer> findAllById(...)
```

Comment: Hi Alan, i try like you sugges with serch, however debugging the source i see that when you user search automatically try to match with custom implementacions, and not use the findAllById method.

Comment: No, [it is not exported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource) but still doesn't work.